# Webservices API - WsCreateError with WS_ERROR_PROPERTY

Tags: windows, web-services, winapi, webservice-client

Is it possible to to create an error obj with WSCreateError with WS_ERROR_PROPERTY set? I am getting E_INVALID_ARG.

```
WS_ERROR_PROPERTY Prop;
DWORD lang_Id = 1033;

Prop.id = WS_ERROR_PROPERTY_LANGID;
Prop.value = (void *)&lang_Id;
Prop.valueSize = sizeof(lang_Id);

WS_ERROR *err = NULL;
HRESULT hr = WsCreateError(&prop, 1, &err);
// returns E_INVALID_ARG
```

Is there anything wrong with the way I am calling this?
An example with any property would be great!

Comment: What is the value of pc?  It better be one, the first argument is an array.

Comment: pc is 1. Any example would really help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lang_id needs to be of type LANGID